# Valid SharePoint user that doesn't have a user profile causing workflow errors

Tags: workflow, user-profile, user-profile-service, exception-handling, error-handling

I have created a work flow that retrieves some details, such as the manager and some address details, about users on our SharePoint.

The information is retrieved for after the fact analysis we do on our companies work which means sometimes the person who's profile the workflow checks no longer works at the company.

The workflow uses the `"Person is a valid sharepoint user"` condition, and if the person still works with us or not, this passes. However if the person no longer works for us they appear to have no user profile or maybe a broken profile. I don't have any kind of admin rights over the environment so I'm not sure how to confirm this.

When the workflow tries to retrieve the persons manager it stops the workflow with the error

> "Workflow failed to get user profile for user:DOMAIN\username."

I've use logging to the history list to make sure it fails at this point. The `"person is a valid sharepoint user"` check is definitely passed.

I've tried creating an if statement that would log to the history list if the return value for retrieving a users manager is empty or not but as soon as it looks for the user profile to do the comparison the workflow stops and neither result is logged.

I can't see how to bypass this issue. If the user has no profile I just need a way to handle that exception and have the workflow continue with it's remaining tasks. Is there a no code way to check that a user profile exists without stopping the whole workflow?

thanks for any advice,
Martin

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?